# The Mean Value Theorem without an equation

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I've done this question a few times but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong... 
In the question, there is a statement and then a graph. 
The question states:

**Applying the Mean Value Theorem with $a = 2$, $b = 7$, and $c = 4$. What is 
the equation of the tangent line at 4?**

Then the figure below the question shows part of circle with the points, $(2, 3)$, $(4, 6)$, $(7, 7)$ and a tangent line passing the point, $(4, 6)$, which, from what I understand, is point $c$.

The answer is a fill in the blanks,

$y =$ ______

---

So, first I wrote out the equation for The Mean Value Theorem:

$${f'(c) = \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b - a}}$$

Then I plugged in the values:

$${f'(4) = \frac{f(7) - f(2)}{7 - 2}}$$

Using the points on the graph, I plug in the f(x) values

$${f'(4) = \frac{7 - 3}{5}}$$

$${f'(4) = \frac{4}{5}}$$

$\frac{4}{5}$, however, is not the answer because I am not looking for $y'$, I'm looking for $y$.

What do I do next? How do I find y?

Comment: Hint: Draw a picture. This tangent line should be parallel to a certain secant line.

Comment: slope of the tangent at $(4,6)$ is $\frac{4}{5}$, you have slope, you have one point on it, can you find it's eqaution?

Comment: It cannot be a circle. With your data I found the equation of the circle and the tangent at $(4,6)$ is not parallel to the line joining the other two points

Comment: It's not a circle and thanks @SeanRoberson but I already have a photo in the question. It's a curved line with a tangent line parallel to point c.

Comment: @Vikram so should the equation for y be 4/5x + 14/5 then?

Comment: Got it, thank you @Vikram

Answer (score 1):

Using the point parallel of the tangent line, point c, and the slope, plug them into the equation $y = mx + b$

$${y = 4/5x + b}$$
$$ 6 = 4/5(4) + b$$
$$14/5 = b$$
$$y = 4/5x + 14/5$$

That is the complete and correct equation for $y$.